# Why exactly did the CIA want to recruit Bourne?

Tags: plot-explanation, jason-bourne

In [Jason Bourne](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4196776/), we learn that Jason's (David Webb) dad, Richard Webb was a CIA analyst that helped create Treadstone.

We learn later that the asset (Vincent Cassel) killed his dad to persuade Bourne to join Treadstone.

Why?

The CIA recruited U.S. Service members (in the novels) into Treadstone and turned them into assassins, so why did they want Bourne specifically? What was so special about him that they couldn't find in any other U.S. Service member?

Comment: usually when you selecting someone to do this kind of delicate work, they analyze you, measure you and watch you to determine your qualities. Webb probably fitted that certain guidelines. not everybody gets passed on these, considering the delicacy of the program, only handful of people may've been chosen. Webb being one, CIA needed him and hence the persuasion

Comment: “We didn’t pick you, you picked us”..........

Comment: @MissouriSpartan - Yes I remember that, but in Jason Bourne they killed his Dad to "motivate" him. Why? Even if he passed all his tests, many soldiers could have passed the same tests.

Comment: He volunteered.